# MS-Access in Sharepoint - what data available?

Tags: vba, ms-access, sharepoint

For better or worse we are launching an Access db from Sharepoint. Note that this db is not PUBLISHED to SP, people just double-click the link and open the db on their desktops.

So now we need to begin imposing the equivalent of some roles-based edit restrictions. I know there is a VBA CurrentWebUser function and a CurrentWebUserGroups which provides some basic data about who's accessing an Office file from Sharepoint. However my reading and limited experimenting with this stuff leads me to suspect that, for Access at least, these will only work with published dbs, and not ones that are just being launched and run locally, like we're doing.

Is there anything I can get from SP in a case like this? Web user and user group would be useful, so would whichever site/page the link is being clicked on. Is any of this available?

Thanks.

rabbit

Answer (score 0):

Well, not in any simple way.

As you've already determined, `Application.CurrentWebUser` just returns Null.

However, there are several ways to query the user information from SharePoint.

The recommended way (also by me) if you're going to work with SharePoint extensively, is to use the CSOM api, which requires a .Net language, so you'll have to create a COM module, authenticate it separately, and that's all a lot of work.

However, if you're only using simple GET requests, you can also use the REST API and re-use the authentication MS Access uses itself (since MS Access uses MSXML2 to submit web requests to SharePoint, we can create our own MSXML2.XMLHTTP object and it will re-use the cookies Access uses).

The following code uses the JSONInterpreter object I've shared [here on GitHub](https://github.com/erikvona/JSONInterpreter). You could convert it to use XML and MSXML if you don't want that dependency, though.

To execute a request, I use the following code, that assumes the Access application is authenticated, but if it isn't, it connects to the SharePoint site using ADO.

(For this code, `MySiteName` is a global variable containing the URL of your SharePoint site, without a trailing slash)

```vb
Public Function SPRestGetJSON(Site As String, Request As String) As String
    Dim tries As Long
    Dim Success As Boolean
    Do
        'Try to execute request
        tries = tries + 1
        Dim xmlHttpReq As Object 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
        Set xmlHttpReq = CreateObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0") 'New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
        xmlHttpReq.Open "GET", Site & Request, False
        xmlHttpReq.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
        xmlHttpReq.setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json;odata=nometadata"
        xmlHttpReq.send
        Dim root As JSONInterpreter
        Set root = New JSONInterpreter
        root.JSON = xmlHttpReq.responseText
        If Not root.Exists("odata.error") Then
            Success = True
        End If
        If Not Success And tries = 1 Then
            'Connect to SharePoint using WSS + ADO to create auth cookies inside  MSXML
            Dim conn As Object 'ADODB.Connection
            Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 'New ADODB.Connection
            conn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;WSS;DATABASE=" & Site
            On Error Resume Next
            conn.Execute "SELECT 1 From SomeTable" 'Execute to non-existent table but connect to sharepoint
            On Error GoTo 0
            conn.Close
        End If
        Loop While tries < 2 And Success = False
        SPRestGetJSON = xmlHttpReq.responseText
End Function
```

Then, we can use that in a simple function:

```vb
Public Function GetSPUsername() As String
    Dim jsi As New JSONInterpreter
    jsi.JSON = SPRestGetJSON(MySiteName, "/_api/Web/CurrentUser")
    GetSPUsername = jsi.item("LoginName").VBAVariant
End Function
```

Getting groups is also available. This code returns an array of dictionary objects, you can view the available keys in the locals window:

```vb
Public Function GetSPGroups() As Variant 'Array of dictionaries
    Dim jsi As New JSONInterpreter
    jsi.JSON = SPRestGetJSON(SiteName, "/_api/Web/CurrentUser/Groups")
    GetSPGroups = jsi.item("value").VBAVariant
End Function
```

Then, to get the title of the first group the current user is a member of in the immediate window, we can use:

```vb
?GetSPGroups(0)!Title
```